# Arduino Teensy++ 2.0 PWM pins assignments

Tags: arduino, pwm, teensy

I was wondering if anyone would be able to tell me what the pwm pin assignments for the Arduino Teensy++ 2.0. I have googled the assignments, however, I have tried two different boards and had an issues connecting to 0, 1, 24, 14, 15, 16 (as in they absolutely do not respond). We tried to use a different breadboard with no luck.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! In order to get useful answers you need to be much more specific with your question. In this case you should provide the code you are using and clearly describe what you mean by "issues" with the pins.

Comment: They do not respond at all.

Comment: How do you know that they don't respond? Are you observing them with an oscilloscope?

Comment: Yes. We also tried using two different breadboards, two different computers with the drivers installed, and two different arduinos.

Answer (score 1):

Any AVR pin function that starts with "OC" is capable of hardware PWM, therefore B4, B5, B6, B7, C4, C5, C6, D0, and D1 are all PWM-capable.

Comment: Very useful information. What I am wondering is while using the "pinMode(motorpin, OUTPUT)" function call, what pins would be capable of replacing the motorpin? We have found that 27, 26, 25 work, but no others. We have tried two different Teensy++ 2.0 boards and two different bread boards.

Comment: If only those work then the support library for the Teensy++ 2.0 is broken and you should talk to PJRC.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use 0, 1, 14, 15, 16, 24, 25, 26, 27 according to this page:
https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_pulse.html

But It seems that you have timer problem because 25, 26 and 27 are in the same timer while the others are in different timers.

I know that some librairies use these timers (https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_timing.html) and can conflict with your PWM control. If you use timers in your code may be you should search in this direction.

Hope it will help you.